# SSH login delay - No credentials cache found

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a jump box in where SSH logins to other servers have started undergoing heavy delays (upwards of 20+ seconds).  This problem is exhibited from this jump box to any destination, logging to the same destination from a different source does not exhibit the same delay.

Below is the verbose output from the SSH client, the delays in debug output are always at `debug1: Miscellaneous failure`:

```
# ssh -vvv x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_5.9p1 (CentrifyDC build 4.5.3-557) (CentrifyDC build 4.5.3-557),OpenSSL 0.9.8k (CentrifyDC build 4.5.3-557) 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: permantently_set_uid getpwnam(root)
debug3: getpwnam returned 0, uid = 0 
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
#######DELAY#######
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

#######DELAY#######
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "x.x.x.x" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 47:4f:f2:cb:0a:f3:47:f7:77:a4:12:d6:a8:81:21:d8
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "x.x.x.x" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.x' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x959db0)
debug3: input_userauth_banner
S
Kernel 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
#######DELAY#######
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

#######DELAY#######
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 89:18:67:ee:6a:09:90:f4:9a:9e:3f:1e:b3:1f:dc:41
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 89:18:67:ee:6a:09:90:f4:9a:9e:3f:1e:b3:1f:dc:41
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to x.x.x.x ([x.x.x.x]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Thu Nov  9 02:30:14 2017 from y.y.y.y
[root@x.x.x.x ~]#
```

Comment: Do you mean "before" or "after"?

Comment: @grawity Edited in the points of delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages come from the Kerberos authentication mechanism, although I can only guess the exact cause for the delays.

- Your client and server both support Kerberos authentication through GSSAPI.

  You don't actually have Kerberos credentials (kinit), but the client doesn't really know that, only the GSSAPI mechanism (Kerberos) does. So as long as GSSAPI is enabled, the client will try to use it regardless.
- Traditionally Kerberos on the client side relies on *reverse DNS* for determining the full domain name of the server. Sometimes rDNS for internal IP addresses is broken in such a way that it won't simply return a success or failure; it won't return a response at all, and the client is forced to wait the entire query timeout. (For example, the ISP's or company's DNS server might have, uh, "protections" which block the reply completely.)

  Kerberos may need to know the domain name in order to find the correct credentials, so it will perform the rDNS check *before* even looking whether you have a credential cache.

Recommendations:

1. Run `time host x.x.x.x` (where x.x.x.x is the server's IP address) and check how long it takes for DNS resolution to happen. An instant failure is okay; a long delay is not.
2. Set the `GSSAPIAuthentication` and `GSSAPIKeyExchange` options in the SSH client to "off", either via command line or *ssh_config(5)*, to temporarily disable Kerberos.
3. If you know that Kerberos isn't supported by your network, disable the same option in the SSH *server* configuration to just skip the process entirely.

   (There's no need to disable it on both sides. If servers don't offer it, clients won't bother trying.)

Although since you actually *have installed* Centrify SSH instead of the usual OpenSSH, I'd guess that you *do* have a working Kerberos setup (or at least had it at some point), and instead of disabling it, looking into fixing it would be a bit better.

Comment: DNS resolution seems to consistantly take over 1 second.  I tested from another box that can login to the same server without the delays and the same amount of delay does not exist.  This looks to be a DNS issue at this time.  I'll report back whether that fixes it. EDIT: Yep, changed the DNS resolver and the delay is gone.  Thanks!